# how to convert an HTML table into an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-excel

I use laravel-excel version 3.1 . 
my code is :

```
class UsersExport implements FromView
{
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = User::query()->select('name' , 'family' , 'mobile' ,'national_code' , 'email' , 'registered_from')->get();
    }

    public function view(): View
    {
        return view('test', [
            'users' => $this->users
        ]);
    }
}
```

In my controller I called vies function:

```
return (new UsersExport())->view();
```

here I got a view (html page) not excel spreadsheet. what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `use Exportable;` in your `UserExport` class, then call `return (new UsersExport())->download('something.xls');`

P. S. It is not a good idea to write query in UserExport constructor. It would be better to get them before calling it, then pass to your `new UserExport()`